# Is it possible to get a Virtualbox VM always start from same host?

Tags: virtualbox

I'm using Virtualbox to deploy Ubuntu VM on remote client site. This VM consist of database and web application. Client don't have access to VM. Only to web application on specific port.

My concern is, client will be able to export this VM and run it on different host. Any solution for this?

I'm thinking of restriction using host UUID or serial number but I'm not able to get that info from VM.

Answer (score 0):

A virtual machine is exactly that, a logically separate machine, so it must have the
same security layers placed on it as you would a bare-metal system.
If the proper steps are taken, virtualization can be extremely secure.

You can add security mechanisms to the VM that will make it unusable
elsewhere than on the intended target computer.

Perhaps the simplest would be to tailor the VM to the client's IP address.
Since the VM has access to the Internet, its external IP is that of the client.
Adding such a check to the startup process will assure that the VM cannot
be used outside of the client's local network.